# Add 2 local locations to same Git repo

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-subtree

I've been googling on Git for a few hours now and I'm going nowhere, so hope you can help.

I have a local path
/path/to/somewhere/
And this is in sync with my remote BitBucket repo
    https://bitbucket.org/company/somewhere.git

Now I want to add another folder like
/path/to/there/
And I want it to appear in the same repository
   https://bitbucket.org/company/somewhere.git/there/

I tried using "git subtree add --prefix=there https://bitbucket.org/company/somewhere.git" but it responds with:

prefix 'somewhere' already exists.

When I log in to Bitbucket and check, it doesnt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git doesn't work like this you have to have one more repository for `/path/to/there/` to be able to include it into your `/path/to/somewhere/` as a sub directory.
When you have two repository you can:

```
$ cd /path/to/somewhere/
$ git subtree add --prefix=there https://bitbucket.org/company/THERE.git master
```

Then a new directory `there` appeares in the `/path/to/somewhere/`.

For more information take a look at [this](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/05/alternatives-to-git-submodule-git-subtree/)

Comment: Thankyou. I ended up using a symbolic link like:  
`cd /path/to/somewhere/`  
`ln -s /path/to/there/ there/`  
It's not pretty, but it gets the job done.